# External USB drive won't stop after shutdown

Tags: 10.04, boot, usb, grub2

After shutdown I notice that both the USB hub and the external USB drive remain active (lights on): the next time I try to boot the system hang after grub and I have to do a hard reboot. After that the system boots fine, until the next shutdown/boot cycle.

Ideas on how to troubleshoot/resolve the issue?

EDIT: The USB hard drive is powered by an adapter, while the hub is self powered; it's a dual-boot machine, with Windows XP on another partition and with Win there's no such a problem.

EDIT #2: It's a PC, and the USB devices remain active **after** the PC's shtudown: I mean, when the pc is completely off, not standby, not hibernated and not suspended. After that the CPU, PSU, GPU and the various fans are completely quiet.

EDIT #3: The problem occurs also if a SD card is in the reader at boot time.

Comment: Hello! Please give me more info, try the same with other machines(ex. with apple/ms), and try with a 10.10 or 9.10 live cd the same, give me the results plz!

Comment: Is this a powered hub? USB Hard drive or flash drive? Self powered drive?

Comment: There may be an option in your BIOS, as there is in mine, that determines whether your USB ports are powered when the computer is turned off.

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu at all.

Comment: That's your point of view: I think that, being Ubuntu the main operating system involved in these strange behaviours, it IS related to Ubuntu. I thought that maybe some other Ubuntu user experienced the same situation and had already faced some workaround. I was wrong...still this it seems to me the right place to ask this question.

Comment: My guess is that Ubuntu/linux doesn't detach (power down) USB devices before shutting down the PC, and somehow that causes issues on your system...

Comment: That's my guess too. The problem is, how to troubleshoot and eventually get rid of it?

Comment: @dag729, I don't mean to sound "mean", but honestly, it doesn't seem to be related to Ubuntu directly. From what you describe, it seems more like this is a problem with the system (hardware) itself. Some systems continue to supply power to devices (and the the motherboard) after you turn them off.

Comment: @Roland Linux does [handle things differently when it comes to shutting down ACPI](https://kracekumar.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/the-linux-3-0-kernel-will-reboot-better/) which, could mean there are similar bugs/quirks in the Linux drivers for USB subsystems. I won't close this as off-topic because Ubuntu is part of the puzzle even if it's not the main cause.

Comment: @Oli, I'm well aware that Linux handles things differently, however I've experienced similar situations with Windows systems; and nothing he says here indicates that it is Ubuntu specific, so honestly this is off topic at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Also, I re-read again before posting, and I think I mis-interpereted your question. By 
after shutdown, do you mean after the PC shuts down, or the process of shutting down, before the PC turns itself off?

---

I am assuming you have a PC, not a laptop. When you shut down your PC, there s still some power flowing through the SMPS (also called the PSU). Thats the reason you can see the hub lit. As for the HDD, it might be connected to the same spike-strip/board as the PSU. After you shut-down the PC, turn off the wall socket too, and see if that works.

Comment: It doesn't work: it just boots one time off of two. No more, no less. I think that it might be involved grub, but I'm not sure on how to troubleshoot that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

Here's why: Because your drive is set to run as long as it has power. There is no way to change that, it's hardware level.

So, the only way to make it stop that is to unplug it.

Apologies if that wasn't what you wanted to hear, but it's the truth as far as I've been able to figure out.

Comment: Of course I did: the problem occurs only when the device is plugged. But I wish I could just let it plugged as any other device.

Comment: The OP has stated that this is an external drive.

Comment: @scouser Apologies - I didn't see that.

Comment: @scouser @dag729 Updated question.

Answer (score 1):

> the next time I try to boot the system hang after grub and I have to do a hard reboot

This may be silly ...any chance it's a grub issue?

if it's a really really *really* OLD version of grub, maybe. 
look in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Do you see UUIDs being used? stuff like:

```
linux   /vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-server root=UUID=b55fdc69-d2fb-4896-89cc-65031a0bcf9f
```

or do you see something like

```
linux /vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-server /dev/sda1
```

if it's the former, nevermind ignore this post ;)

if it's the latter, then well you might want to edit those /dev/sdXY pointers to UUIDs, because the USB device might be taking over that device name (which is possible with today's BIOSes)